# Using Flask-Table how do I change the tables design?

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-table

I'm using `Flask-Table` and I don't know how to change the `html` design of the table. Does anybody know how I do so?

Comment: Can you provide some more details, images or other insigths?

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation, [https://flask-table.readthedocs.io/en/stable/]. @PaulHigazi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add CSS design you will need a CSS class as such:

```
table.blueTable {
   border: 1px solid #4169E1;
  background-color: #008CBA;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.blueTable td, table.blueTable th {
  border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
  padding: 3px 2px;;
}
table.blueTable tbody td {
  font-size: 13px;
}
table.blueTable tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #15AAE1;
}
table.blueTable thead {
  background: #1C6EA4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #5592bb 0%, #327cad 66%, #1C6EA4 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444444;
}
table.blueTable thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #E1E1E1;
  border-left: 2px solid #D0E4F5;
}
table.blueTable thead th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

table.blueTable tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
table.blueTable tfoot .links {
  text-align: right;
}
table.blueTable tfoot .links a{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #1C6EA4;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And you will need to apply the class to the table as seen in this code:

```
room_table = User_Room_Table(items=RoomHelper.get_by_user(user_name=current_user.username), border=11,
                                 classes=['blueTable']
```